# UILabel auto size error on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I'm making my app transition to iOS 7 and have this method (already modified for iOS 7, using `boundingRectWithSize`...):

```
+ (CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message {

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:13]};

    CGRect frame = [message boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attributes context:nil];

    return frame.size;
}
```

I am getting this appearance:

[image: bubble]

The message `UILabel` is being cut. It feels like line spacing is too big. It tried many other answers I found but none of them work.

If someone knows how to help me, I appreciate! ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add autolayout constraint to the label in IB? Try to get rid of height constraint of Label.

Comment: No, I'm not using auto layout in IB.

Comment: Ask the dev forums until iOS 7 is public.

Comment: Where did you call this method ?

Comment: It's called in `layoutSubviews` of a custom UITableViewCell class.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading` as your option to `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`.

If you were only supporting iOS 6 and iOS 7, then I would definitely change all of your NSString's `sizeWithFont:...` to the NSAttributeString's `boundingRectWithSize`.  Starting in iOS 6, the NSAttributedString's NSStringDrawing functions were introduced and they're threadsafe unlike the old NSString+UIKit methods we're used to (eg. `sizeWithFont:...`, etc), which were UIStringDrawing functions (and act unpredictably when you use them from a non-main thread.  It'll save you a lot of headache if you happen to have a weird multi-threading corner case!  Here's how I converted NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`:

What used to be:

```
NSString *text = ...;
CGFloat width = ...;
UIFont *font = ...;
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font 
               constrainedToSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}];
```

Can be replaced with:

```
NSString *text = ...;
CGFloat width = ...;
UIFont *font = ...;
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:text
        attributes:@
        {
            NSFontAttributeName: font
        }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
```

Please note the documentation mentions:

> In iOS 7 and later, this method returns fractional sizes (in the size
>   component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size
>   views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer
>   using the ceil function.

So to pull out the calculated height or width to be used for sizing views, I would use:

```
CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);
CGFloat width  = ceilf(size.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are updating your label frame from either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, so it is not working.

if you will update frame of label from viewDidAppear method then you will get updated frame of label.

I am not sure why this is happened, I think it is iOS 7 bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
+ (CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message {

CGSize nameSize = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:13]
                      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", nameSize.width, nameSize.height);

return nameSize;
}
```

Comment: This function has been deprecated in iOS 7. It doesn't work properly